# How to run intent on adapter from fragment to activity in android studio

Tags: android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-fragmentactivity

I would like to move layout from `recyclerview` in adapter, and i want to move layout using fragment to activity and I create intent on an adapter from fragment to activity,
here is my Adapter :

```
public class VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public VerifikasiPembayaranFragment pembayaranFragment;
    public VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter() {}
@NonNull
    @Override
    public VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
               .inflate(R.layout.list_verifikasi_pembayaran,viewGroup,false);
       final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
       viewHolder.list_verifikasi_pembayaran.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(pembayaranFragment.getContext(), VerifikasiPembayaranActivity.class);
           pembayaranFragment.startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
       return viewHolder;
    }
}
```

and the error say :
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity com.example.umroini.belajar.Fragment.VerifikasiPembayaranFragment.getActivity()' on a null object reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should not handle all related to Intent inside the Adapter. Your Adapter should only handling how the data is presented to the user. All related to the data manipulation, processing, etc should be delegated back to the Fragment or Activity. Hence, you need to use Listener.

First, create the listener in your Adapter.

```
public class VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface Listener {
        void onItemClicked(YourDataItem item);
    }

    private Listener listener;

    public VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

       ...

       viewHolder.list_verifikasi_pembayaran.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              listener.onItemClicked(yourItem);
           }
       });

       return viewHolder;
    }
}
```

Second and last, use the adapter in your Activity or Fragment:

```
VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter.Listener listener = new VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter.Listener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClicked(YourDataItem item) {
      // Here you handling the click listener of item.
      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VerifikasiPembayaranActivity.class);
      pembayaranFragment.startActivity(intent);
   }
};
VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter adapter = new VerifikasiPembayaranAdapter(listener);
```

Comment: what is mean of YourDataItem

Comment: It's your data item. Each item from your List in the adapter.